# error: No module named 'register.forms', using crispy-forms django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to install a django user registration module in crispy-forms and I am getting the error:

```
No module named 'register.forms'
```

The exact line giving me issues appears to be

```
from .forms import RegisterForm
```

I do have crispy-forms installed

```
(secret) user@client:~/www/src/exchange $ pip3 install django-crispy-forms
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: django-crispy-forms in /home/kermit/Env/secret/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.9.0)
```

.

```
(secret) user@client:~/www/src/exchange $ cat register/views.py              
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
#from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .forms import RegisterForm

# Create your views here.
def register(response):
        if response.method == "POST":
                form = RegisterForm(response.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                        form.save()

                return redirect("home/")
        else:
                form = RegisterForm()

        form = UserCreationForm()
        return render(response, "register/register.html",{"form":form})



(secret) user@client:~/www/src/exchange $ cat register/form.py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
#from django.models import models


class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = models.EmailField()

        class Meta:
                model = User
                fields = ["username", "email", "password1", "password2"]
```

.

```
(secret) user@client:~/www/src/exchange $ cat exchange/urls.py                                 
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from pages.views import home_view, contact_view, about_view, user_view
from userdash.views import userdash_detail_view, userdash_create_view
from django.conf.urls import include

from register import views as v
from pages import views

urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.home_view, name='home'),
        path('', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path("register/", v.register, name="register"),
        path('userdash/', userdash_detail_view),
        path('contact/', contact_view),
        path('create/', userdash_create_view),
        path('about/', about_view),
        path('user/', user_view),
]
```

.

```
(secret) user@client:~/www/src/exchange $ cat exchange/settings.py 

import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SECRET_KEY = '*snicker*'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['10.9.8.30','192.168.43.252','127.0.0.1','192.168.42.13','localhost','192.168.42.12']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    #mystuff
        'userdash',
        'pages',
#    'userdash.apps.UserdashConfig',
        'register.apps.RegisterConfig',
        'crispy_forms',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'exchange.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'exchange.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/home/user/www/src/exchange/db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK="bootstrap4"
```

verbose error output:

```
ModuleNotFoundError at /register/

No module named 'register.forms'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.42.13:8080/register/
Django Version:     2.2.7
Exception Type:     ModuleNotFoundError
Exception Value:    

No module named 'register.forms'

Exception Location:     ./register/views.py in <module>, line 4
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
Python Version:     3.7.3
Python Path:    

['.',
 '',
 '/home/kermit/Env/secret/lib/python37.zip',
 '/home/kermit/Env/secret/lib/python3.7',
 '/home/kermit/Env/secret/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7',
 '/home/kermit/Env/secret/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

I looked at other urls and none appeared to address the same error.

How do I load the module 'forms'?

Comment: Your file is named `form.py` not `forms.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in your `register/views.py`, line 4. You are trying to import from `.forms`, which is the current app's `forms.py`. You must not have a file named `register/forms.py`.

Either change the import from `from .form import RegisterForm` or change the filename of `register/form.py` to `register/forms.py`. The latter is the solution recommended by conventions.

Comment: That was it. I'll accept it in after the 5 min limit is up. thank you.